# Extract id and corresponding tokens and append to dictionary from file python

Tags: python, dictionary, machine-learning, nlp

I'm trying to create a dictionary from some text files which define a corpus(RCV1 dataset tokens).I've cleaned the file from some stopwords with the help of regex.Originally it looked like this: https://ibb.co/h3eG5v. I cleaned the stopwords with this code:

```
def cleanFile():
    infile = "lyrl2004_tokens_train.dat"
    outfile = "cleaned_file.dat"

    delete_list = [".W",'.I ']
    fin = open(infile)
    fout = open(outfile, "w+")

    for line in fin:
        for word in delete_list:
            line = line.replace(word, "")
    fout.write(line)
    fin.close()
    fout.close()
```

And then used a small code chunk to remove any blank lines as well.Now the text files basically look like this: https://ibb.co/e7Ww5v

So now the format is a line with the document id,integer(2286-26150 for the training data),then multiple lines with the tokens seperated by a single space and then the block repeats:

2286

token token token token token token

token token token token token

2287

token token token..

What I'm trying to accomplish is write a function that will read the entire file which thankfully can fit into memory,then construct a dictionary with the document ID and its corresponding tokens inside a list.It should look like this : {'2286':[token,token,token....],'2287':[token,token,token...],...}. I'm out of ideas because I can't find a way to repeatedly process text between two consecutive numbers,since everything I've searched for usually includes delimiters that are not numbers.
Just for the info,I'm going to construct a text classifier next with this data (which is why I need a dictionary).The test tokens are in the same format as the training ones,with higher integers up to 800.000

Comment: Can any token be a number?

Comment: Very few of them are,I could skip them altogether since they don't provide any relevant information to the document's topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code if a token is never a number:

```
text = '''123
dpqvjp jpo fjiqo iq[woe f
wf q  q[ewfp wqervg
436
oiwbrveojibnpibn eprvnj erv p eprwoij
536
oiberv ih reip rewp wepri pirvnep
erpvj pre
er
erpno poj rgwe epo
'''
dct = {}
current_id = None
for el in text.split():
    if el.isdigit():
        current_id = el
        dct[current_id] = []
    else:
        dct[current_id].append(el)
print(dct)
```

Result:

```
{'123': ['dpqvjp', 'jpo', 'fjiqo', 'iq[woe', 'f', 'wf', 'q', 'q[ewfp', 'wqervg'], '536': ['oiberv', 'ih', 'reip', 'rewp', 'wepri', 'pirvnep', 'erpvj', 'pre', 'er', 'erpno', 'poj', 'rgwe', 'epo'], '436': ['oiwbrveojibnpibn', 'eprvnj', 'erv', 'p', 'eprwoij']}
```

If there're numbers among the tokens, you can invent a pattern for your `id`, for example:

```
<ID=2647>
```

So your document will look like this:

```
<ID=123>
dpqvjp jpo fjiqo iq[woe f
wf q  q[ewfp wqervg
<ID=436>
oiwbrveojibnpibn eprvnj erv p eprwoij
<ID=536>
oiberv ih reip rewp wepri pirvnep
erpvj pre
er
erpno poj rgwe epo
```

And you should parse it with this code:

```
import re
text = '''<ID=123>
dpqvjp jpo fjiqo iq[woe f
wf q  q[ewfp wqervg
<ID=436>
oiwbrveojibnpibn eprvnj erv p eprwoij
<ID=536>
oiberv ih reip rewp wepri pirvnep
erpvj pre
er
erpno poj rgwe epo
'''
dct = {}
current_id = None
for el in text.split():
    match = re.match(r'<ID=(\d+)>', el)
    if match:
        current_id = match.group(1)
        dct[current_id] = []
    else:
        dct[current_id].append(el)
print(dct)
```

Comment: Script gives me KeyError:None.I read the data from the file to the string with this :  trainData=myfile.read().replace('\n', '') .
After trying to print the el,it seems that it read "2286recov"(start of first document with its ID) and then execution stopped.

Comment: Do `trainData=myfile.read().replace('\n', ' ')` instead (with the white space).

Comment: `KeyError:None` may appear only if your data doesn't start with `id`.

Comment: It works!Thanks a lot.I might have a few problems with the documents containing numbers,since they are so few I might as well remove them manually else I'm gonna search for a way to create ID Tag from the integers.

Comment: I'm getting some weird behaviour.This works fine for the train documents but for the test ones instead of getting a dict with length 200571 I get only 99933 keys.What could be the cause of this?